# ESP8266MOD programing using Arduino uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, esp8266

I want to make a very simple webserver who sends welcome message to anyone who joins it using WiFi.

I have a ESP8266MOD module, I want to program it using arduino ide and arduino uno board.
How I can use arduino uno to program this WiFi module without using urat USB serial board?

SoftwareSerial.h is not working with esp.write() command, I believe it is because of low power, can anyone suggest me on power supply too?

Thanks in advance,

Mohan

Comment: Why use a mini to tell a Ferrari what to do? Program the esp8266 directly and screw the Arduino.

Comment: just short the UNO's reset to ground to use it as an "FTDI" to program the ESP from the Arduino IDE

Comment: Hi dandavis, can you please show me an example, because how to use UNO as FTDI is not documented well anywhere...

Comment: your absolutely right Majenko, but my problem is that I don't have URAT or FTDI, so to connect to IDE I have to use UNO itself as FTDI

Comment: rx>tx,tx>Rx,gnd<gnd, on avr: rst to gnd. then you can use at mode et al

Comment: Making Rx > Tx and Tx > Rx not sending data, more I got a weird error now, I was able to connect it, and blue light is blinking, I can also found it working in my phone's wifi list. but in IDE when I try to upload the sketch I am getting error: error: Failed to open COM1
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_open failed,

Answer (score 1):

When you use the Uno for its UART only, i.e. grounding RST pin, its Rx pin 0 becomes Tx, and Tx pin 1 becomes Rx -- because that's what pins on the UART you are connecting to. AppMonk didn't say what specific breakout/ chip mount he's using, there are many, or say how he's managing level-shifting from the Uno to the ESP if needed. The Tx pin on Uno (0, labeled Rx) is putting out 5v and the ESP would prefer 3.3, so level shifting w/ simple voltage divider is recommended. You don't need to level shift the Tx signal from ESP to Arduino's Rx (pin 1).